# how to print stl files (3d) in java

Tags: java, printing, 3d

As part of my school project, I have stl files and I need to print them one by one in 3d printer.
How do i send it to the printer? is there a function that does that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use java print api and send the file to a 3D printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending commands to a 3d printer is a very large subject. In short, what has to be done is:

1. An `.stl` file is a collection of **polygons**. A 3D printer cannot process those. Most 3D printers receive movement commands. These commands are called `G code`. Converting `stl` files to `g codes` is called **slicing**. There are softwares which do that. For example, the open source [slic3r](http://slic3r.org/). You can try the `console-slic3r` to see how it works and use it within your Java code.
2. After you have a G code file, you have to send them to the printers. Most 3D printers can communicate with your computer using serial communication. You have to connect to the right port, then start sending the G code line by line. Every time the printer finishes performing a command, it sends back an 'ok' response (It's `ok` for Marlin based printers, open a serial monitor and start experimenting yourself to see how your printer behaves). Every time you receive an `ok`, you send the next command, until you are out of them.

So basically what you have to do (in steps)

1. Using Slic3r, convert your `.stl` file to `.gcode` file.
2. Read the output `.gcode` file that slic3r has generated.
3. Open a serial connection to the printer and send the first line of the file.
4. Wait for `ok`, and send the next line.
5. Repeat step 4 until you are out of `gcode` lines.

If you're new to this subject, I would download the [Arduino IDE](http://arduino.cc/), open the serial monitor, and start sending some G codes to the printer.

**Some examples of G codes**

For example, the movement command is `G0` or `G1`, and it has 6 parameters - `X, Y, Z, E and F` (e - extruder, f - speed). Try: (remember to send a newline after that)

```
G1 X50 Y20 Z10 F5000
```

And the printer is supposed to move to that coordinate. More information about G code commands can be found [here](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code) (G code RepRap wiki)